# Is there any way to remove/nullify an antimagic field without disjunction?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

An *[antimagic field](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/antimagicField.html)* remains if the caster is killed or incapacitated, can't be affected by dispel magic, and only has a partial chance (generally 20% at best) of being affected by *[mage's disjunction](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/mageSDisjunction.html)*. As far as I can gather from the description, *[spell immunity](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/spellImmunity.html)* won't work either.

Is there any remotely reliable way of either taking down an antimagic field or rendering oneself immune to its effects? Counterspelling is an obvious possibility, but only if you're prepared for it, and a [ring of counterspells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-counterspells) won't work because AMF isn't a targeted spell.

I'm not interested in ways to wait out the problem. Researching a reverse time stop spell to speed up the AMF caster's duration expiration speed is also out of the question.

Comment: Drat, that puts paid to my "Sit back with a good book" answer, then. Would you be open to answers that require the possession of particular artefacts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Aroden's Spellbane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/aroden-s-spellbane) is an obvious choice if Disjunction is on the table, allowing you to do this and also block Dispel Magic, Greater Dispel magic, Mage's Disjuction, and other copies of itself if you want.  Or just Anti-magic field.  That's good too.